# How to implement each_slice in rails-react views?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-rails

I have Parent component Monsters, there i render Monster component.

```
for monster in @state.monsters
      React.createElement Monster, key: monster.id, monster: monster, team: @state.team...
```

Inside monster:

```
div className: 'col-md-4',
  hr {}
  img
    className: 'img-responsive img-circle thumbnail'
```

....

Problem there is a bootstrap columns and rows, its break. I need method like each slice, to wrap each(3) objects into bootstrap row.
I used lodash _chunk, and custom Array.prototype variants, but react variables not aviable inside this loops.

```
Array::each_slice = (size, callback) ->
  i = 0
  l = @length
  while i < l
    callback.call this, @slice(i, i + size)
    i += size
```

This is function for each slice, and then i make this.

```
@state.array.each_slice 3, (slice) ->
  for component in slice
    React.createElement Monster, key: component.id, monster: component, team: @state.team etc....
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'team' of undefined

Can anybody help me?

Comment: are you able to get @state in your views?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `@` is different inside the `each_slice` callback. To see the difference, try this:

```
console.log(@) # `@` is the React component
@state.array.each_slice 3, (slice) =>
  console.log(@) # `@` is `window`, the global object
  for component in slice
    React.createElement Monster, team: @state.team # ...
```

To preserve the value `@` inside the callback, use a "fat-arrow" (`=>`), like this:

```
console.log(@) # the React component
@state.array.each_slice 3, (slice) =>
  console.log(@) # still the React component :)
  for component in slice
    React.createElement Monster, team: @state.team # ...
```